# Tables and tabulating variables

Tags: r

I am trying to reproduce this table below. I have a categorical variable (pol_group) which I am trying to tabulate with quantitative variables (education, income, and expense), so that I can see the summary statistics for these variables for each value of pol_group.

```
pol_group           education   income     expense
1             mean  12.67519    29155.54   20710
1             sd    2.916582    22031.51   18321.69
1             min   2           700        700
1             max   25          91952      98242
2             mean  11.26422    21922.08   16254.64
2             sd    3.19276     20088.66   14930.75
2             min   0           700        700
2             max   25          91952      98242
```

Here's a sample of my data:

```
pol_group       education   income     expense
1               16          29258.71   29615
2               14          24062.49   26348.60
1               8           19281.74   23023
1               16          27224      26481
2               18          30102.65   29178.63
2               19          29873.44   27145
1               11          21435.11   24076.55
1               17          28453.99   28312
```

Does anyone know how to create a table structured in this way? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Provide your sample data using `dput(x)`

Comment: @NadPat, I'm generally a fan of `dput(.)` as well, but in this case the current is sufficient: highlight, copy, then `read.table("clipboard",header=TRUE)` (or some os-dependent variant).

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do what you want in R.  I wrote a package called `tables` that can do it.  It's mainly aimed at tables to include in a publication, but if all you want are the numbers so you can compute with them, it can do that too.

The idea of it is that you put together a formula that describes the rows (on the left hand side) and columns (on the right hand side).  Your desired table would be

```r
    vals <- structure(list(pol_group = c(1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1), education = c(16, 
    14, 8, 16, 18, 19, 11, 17), income = c(29258.71, 24062.49, 19281.74, 
    27224, 30102.65, 29873.44, 21435.11, 28453.99), expense = c(29615, 
    26348.6, 23023, 26481, 29178.63, 27145, 24076.55, 28312)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -8L))

    library(tables)
    tabular( Factor(pol_group)*(mean + sd + min + max) ~ 
             education + income + expense, data = vals)
#>                                         
#>  pol_group      education income expense
#>  1         mean 13.600    25131  26302  
#>            sd    3.912     4481   2773  
#>            min   8.000    19282  23023  
#>            max  17.000    29259  29615  
#>  2         mean 17.000    28013  27557  
#>            sd    2.646     3423   1459  
#>            min  14.000    24062  26349  
#>            max  19.000    30103  29179
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

If you want to compute, you would save the result of the `tabular()` call in a variable, say `tab`, then do something like

```r
tab <- tabular( Factor(pol_group)*(mean + sd + min + max) ~ 
                  education + income + expense, data = vals)
as.matrix(tab, format = as.numeric)
#>           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
#> [1,] 13.600000 25130.710 26301.510
#> [2,]  3.911521  4481.471  2772.750
#> [3,]  8.000000 19281.740 23023.000
#> [4,] 17.000000 29258.710 29615.000
#> [5,] 17.000000 28012.860 27557.410
#> [6,]  2.645751  3423.040  1459.393
#> [7,] 14.000000 24062.490 26348.600
#> [8,] 19.000000 30102.650 29178.630
```